# Gunicorn and Django with Upstart and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, virtualenv, gunicorn, upstart

First of all I have many Django instances setup and running like this.

In each project I have a script.sh shell script that starts gunicorn etc.:

```
 #!/bin/bash
  set -e
  LOGFILE=/var/log/gunicorn/app_name.log
  LOGDIR=$(dirname $LOGFILE)
  NUM_WORKERS=3
  # user/group to run as
  USER=root
  GROUP=root
  PORT=8060
  IP=127.0.0.1
  cd /var/www/webapps/app_name
  source ../bin/activate
  test -d $LOGDIR || mkdir -p $LOGDIR
  exec /var/www/webapps/bin/gunicorn_django -b $IP:$PORT -w $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE
```

**When running this script from the command line with *bash script.sh*, the site works perfectly, so Nginx is setup right.**

As soon as I use upstart with **service app_name start the** app starts and then just stops. It does not even write to the log file.

This is the **app_name.conf** file in **/etc/init/app_name.conf** :

```
description "Test Django instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
respawn limit 10 5
exec /var/www/webapps/app_name/script.sh
```

So what is the problem here? Cause running from command line works, but doing trough upstart does not. And I dont know where to see whats wrong?

Comment: Damn this is frustrating, im sure im blind or something and not seeing the problem!

Comment: Even when running this fomr command line gunicorn_django -b $IP:$PORT -w $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP --log-level=debug --log-file=$LOGFILE 2>>$LOGFILE everything works. It must be that upstart is the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. If any one ever run into something like this...

Its basically a lack of knowledge about shell scripts that was holding me back.

After commenting out each line o the script file i found the problem with the line : **source ../bin/activate** and all after that.

The problem was that it had 2 spaces on front of it, and now I know it needs to be left aligned all the way. Now it works.

This is how i figured it out:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jun 26 10:54:59 saturn7 init: app_name main process (3521) terminated with status 127
```

I found out that status 127 is basically a command that is not found. So I know the problem was actually in the script file.

But I am not sure why bash ./script.sh would work and not tell me anything is wrong? I need to read up about schell scripts..

Comment: I start all my upstart scripts with `exec >/var/log/${UPSTART_JOB}.log 2>&1` followed by `set -x` - this outputs every line executed to /var/log/[upstart-job].log and you get a clear idea why and when something fails. I got caught up by setuid not supported on an earlier version of upstart